# How can I show the date of database in this code?

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

```
@foreach($documentos as $documento)
        <ul class="mail-list">
            <li class="mail-item unread">
                <div class="m-chck"><label class="px-single"><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="px"><span class="lbl"></span></label></div>
                <div class="m-star"><a href="#"> </a></div>
                <div class="m-from"><a href="#">{{$documento->assunto}} </a></div>
                <div class="m-subject"><span class="label label-danger">Social</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="pages-show-email.html">Reset your account password</a></div>
                <div class="m-date">3:25 PM</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        @endforeach
```

I need show the date from BD... I need show the date from BD, cause iam using pixelAdmin

Comment: Which variable contains the date here? Whats your current date format on that variable?

Answer (score 0):

`Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y')` or you can change the format to however you need

I would suggest you do this in the controller and pass it to the view

Laravel has a Carbon dependency attached to it but you can find the [Carbon doc](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)  and see how it works

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) for formatting timestamp. In laravel migration file you will find 2 default timestamp columns. one is created_at and another is updated_at. If you want to show the time when the document is created you can use `$documento->created_at` with Carbon for readable format.

Here is an example,

```
{{  \Carbon\Carbon::parse($documento->created_at)->toFormattedDateString() }}
```

The output will be similar to Dec 25, 1975.

Comment: My problem isn't the timestamp or time or another atribute... Is about the view... I mean... How can i display the date from database ??  Ex:  <td>{{ $candidatura->id}}</td>   VS       <div class="m-from"><a href="#">{{$documento->assunto}} </a></div>